# How to move files with a keyword with a lookup file using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of IDs in a CSV file stored in a folder. Then I have files which contains these IDs. I want to move the files if it is present in the CSV file.

For example:

I have this documents in `Docs` folder: `Jose_1234_CV.pdf`, `Jose_111_CV.doc`, `Jose_2323_CV.doc`

I have `IDs.csv` file containing the following IDs: `1234`, `111`

When I run the batch job, the files with the IDs `1234` and `111` should be moved to a particular folder.

I have the below code working only if in the look up file contains the exact file name. I want it work even if it only find the ID:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\users\directory"
set "Target=C:\users\target"
set "FileList=C:\users\lookup\ID.csv"
echo/

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto :Quit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto :Quit
2> nul md "%Target%"

for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%FileList%") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\%%a"') do (
        move "%%b" "%Target%"
    )
)

:Quit
echo/
echo Press the Space bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: use `findstr` see help by `findstr /?`

Comment: Have you tried to replace `dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\%%a"` by `dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\*_%%a_*"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseDirectory=C:\Users"
set "Source=%BaseDirectory%\directory"
set "Target=%BaseDirectory%\target"
set "FileList=%BaseDirectory%\lookup\IDs.csv"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

if not exist "%Source%\" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found. & goto Quit
if not exist "%Source%\*_*_CV.*" echo Folder "%Source%" does not contain any *_*_CV.* file. & goto Quit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found. & goto Quit
md "%Target%" 2>nul
if not exist "%Target%\" echo Folder "%Target%" could not be created. & goto Quit

set "FileMoved=0"
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

rem Create a copy of list file with each identifer surrounded by underscores
rem to make sure that on an identifier like 111 just the file with _111_ in
rem name and not with _2111_ or _1114_ in name is moved to target folder.
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%FileList%") do echo _%%~I_>>"%TempFile%"

rem Move all files containing one of the identifiers in
rem temporary file in its file name to the target folder.
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Source%\*_*_CV.*" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /G:"%TempFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    move /Y "%%I" "%Target%\%%~nxI" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 set /A FileMoved+=1
)

rem Delete the temporary file no longer needed.
del "%TempFile%"

rem Delete the target directory if being empty.
if %FileMoved% == 0 rd "%Target%" 2>nul

rem Inform user about number of moved files.
set "Plural_S=s"
if %FileMoved% == 1 set "Plural_S="
echo Moved %FileMoved% *.csv file%Plural_S% to "%Target%".

:Quit
endlocal
echo/
echo Press SPACE to close this window.
pause >nul
```

This batch code expects that the file `C:\Users\lookup\IDs.csv` contains the identifiers line by line like:

```
1234
111
```

The first **FOR** command creates a copy of `IDs.csv` with the lines:

```
_1234_
_111_
```

The second **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background (= not visible) the command line:

```
dir "C:\Users\directory\*_*_CV.*" /A-D-H /B /S 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /L /G:"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\BatchFileName.tmp" 2>nul
```

So the command process in background with no console window is first running command **DIR** which outputs

- all non hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*_*_CV.*`
- in bare format because of `/B` which means file name only
- in specified directory and all its subdirectories because of `/S`
- with full path also because of `/S`
- to handle **STDOUT**.

**DIR** outputs an error message if it can't find any file matching the wildcard pattern. This error message written to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`.

The file names with full path output by **DIR** line by line to handle **STDOUT** are redirected with `|` to handle **STDIN** of next command **FINDSTR**.

**FINDSTR** searches in the list of file names for

- any string listed in temporary file specified after `/G:`
- case-sensitive because of **not** using `/I`
- and literally because of using `/L`
- and outputs the lines (= file names with full path) containing one of the strings in the temporary file.

That means no directory in path of a file should contain `_ID_` or otherwise files are moved which do not contain the identifier in file name, but in its path.

It is possible that **FINDSTR** can't find any line matching the search criteria and therefore outputs an error message to handle **STDERR** which is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to device **NUL**.

The command **FOR** captures the output written to handle **STDOUT** of the background command process which is the output of **DIR** filtered with **FINDSTR** and then processes this output line by line.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR**. But that does not matter here as the list of file names each with full path does not contain empty lines.

Lines starting with a semicolon would be also ignored by **FOR**, but this behavior is modified with `eol=|` to ignore just lines starting with a vertical bar. A vertical bar is impossible here as no directory or file can contain a vertical bar in name. Well, it is also practically impossible that a file name with full path starts with a semicolon. So `eol=|` would not be really needed here.

**FOR** with parameter `/F` splits by default a line up into substrings using space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assign only the first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This split behavior is not wanted here as needed in body command block of **FOR** is always the full qualified name of a file to move even on path or file name contains a space character. For that reason `delims=` is specified to define an empty list of delimiters which disables splitting up the lines into substrings.

**MOVE** is executed which moves the file and exits with `0` on success and with any value greater `0` on an error.

The exit code of an executed application or command is assigned by Windows command interpreter to environment variable `ERRORLEVEL`.

The **IF** condition checks if **MOVE** exited **not** with a value **greater or equal** `1`, i.e. with `0` (or a negative value) for success. In this case file was moved successfully and the appropriate counter is increased by one.

If the source directory contains never subdirectories, it would be better to use for second **FOR** loop:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Source%\*_*_CV.*" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /G:"%TempFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    move /Y "%Source%\%%I" "%Target%\%%I" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 set /A FileMoved+=1
)
```

**DIR** is here without `/S` and so output are the non hidden files matching the wildcard pattern without path. For that reason **FINDSTR** searches in file name only for `_ID_`. The command **MOVE** must contain `%Source%\` as `%%I` is in this case just the name of a file without path.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.